# Tabs not working with generated serve id

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have this jQuery file

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {        
     var orderId= <%= OrderLi.ClientID %>;

    jQuery("#ApprovalTab").css("display", "block");
    jQuery("#ApprovalLi").css("background-color", "#5EA8DE");
    jQuery("#ApprovalLi a").css("color", "#FFF");
    jQuery("#OrdersTab").css("display", "none");
    jQuery("#ApprovalLi a").css("border-bottom", "3px #5EA8DE solid");

    jQuery("#ApprovalLi").click(function() {
        jQuery("#ApprovalTab").css("display", "block");
        jQuery("#ApprovalLi").css("background-color", "#5EA8DE");
        jQuery("#ApprovalLi a ").css("color", "#FFF");
        jQuery("#orderId a").css("color", "black");
        jQuery("#Arrow").css("margin-left", "15px");
        jQuery("#ApprovalLi a").css("border-bottom", "3px #5EA8DE solid");
        jQuery("#orderId a").css("border-bottom", "3px #D8D9DC solid");
        jQuery("#orderId").css("background-color", "#F0F1F4");
        jQuery("#OrdersTab").css("display", "none");

    });

    jQuery("orderId").click(function() {
        jQuery("#ApprovalTab").css("display", "none");
        jQuery("#OrdersTab").css("display", "block");
        jQuery("#Arrow").css("margin-left", "112px");
        jQuery("#orderId").css("background-color", "#5EA8DE");
        jQuery("#orderId a").css("border-bottom", "3px #5EA8DE solid");
        jQuery("#ApprovalLi a").css("border-bottom", "3px #D8D9DC solid");
        jQuery("#ApprovalLi").css("background-color", "#F0F1F4");
        jQuery("#orderId a").css("color", "#FFF");
        jQuery("#ApprovalLi a").css("color", "black");


    });

    jQuery("#orderId").hover(function() {
        jQuery("#orderId a").css("border-bottom", "3px #5EA8DE solid");
    });

    jQuery("#ApprovalLi").hover(function() {
        jQuery("#ApprovalLi a").css("border-bottom", "3px #5EA8DE solid");
    });
  });
```

It is applied to this:

```
<ul class="etabs">
<li id="ApprovalLi"><a href="#stopAtTop">Approval </a></li>
<li id="OrderLi" runat="server"  ><a href="#stopAtTop">Orders</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I don't use runat="server" code works just fine, but when I use it, code doesn't render. I've searched something on the Internet, but the only thing I found about this was 'the ID is changing'. I already knew that and you can see in the jQuery above that I am using the server ID.

btw: I know I could optimize the code above, but I want it to work firstly.

What else could be the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is just a guess, but your server side language may be applying ID's to your elements, and you can only have one ID so the one jQuery is trying to access doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the variable `orderId` to the `ClientID` using:

```
var orderId= <%= OrderLi.ClientID %>;
```

The value of `ClientID` will need to be enclosed in quotes to make it a string literal, though (initially missed this, thanks to Yuriy), otherwise this in itself would cause problems:

```
var orderId= '<%= OrderLi.ClientID %>';
```

But then don't seem to utilise that at all, and instead try to access some `orderId` thing using two other methods, both of which use hard-coded string literals in the jQuery selectors:

```
 jQuery("orderId")
```

and

```
 jQuery("#orderId")
```

Now the first is looking for an element (or rather all elements of) `orderId` and the second for an element with an identifier of `"orderId"`. Therefore, it's entirely incidental that your code just works *without* `runat="server"` and seems to break upon *adding* `runat="server"`.

What you want is to actually use your variable:

```
jQuery(orderId)
```

And to be more accurate, given that you're working with identifiers in the selector:

```
jQuery("#" + orderId)
```

It might be more useful prefixing the variable value with the hash instead of each usage (depending on total usage).

Comment: To be absolutely accurate, surround `<%= OrderLi.ClientID %>` with quotes. IAW it will be considered as variable;

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy Good spot, totally breezed over that one.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I could say it was a good mistake and I can learn something from your explanation.